# Proving the normal convergence of a Laurent series using ML-inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, laurent-series

Let $f$ $\in$ $\mathcal{H}$$(ann(a;R_1,R_2))$ and let $(a_n)$ the sequence defined by
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta -a|=r_2}\frac{f(\zeta )}{(\zeta-a)^{n+1}}d\zeta$$
I need to show that for every $R_1<r_2<R_2$, the Laurent serie $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is normally convergent inside the closed disk $\bar{D}(a,r_2)$.

Here is what I've done. Let $\varepsilon>0$ small enough such that $R_1<r_2<r_2+\varepsilon<R_2$. Without loss of generality, we may consider the case $a=0$.  Let $z$ such that $R_1\leq|z|\leq r_2$, so $|z| \leq r_2<r_2+\varepsilon=|\zeta|$ for every $\zeta$ on the circle of radius $r_2+\varepsilon$. This implies that
$$\frac{1}{\zeta-z}=\frac{1}{\zeta}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{\zeta}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{\zeta^{n+1}}$$
which is normally convergent with respect of $\zeta$. So, we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r_2+\varepsilon}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta)z^n$$
Now, we need to see that this series is indeed normally convergent inside the closed disk $\bar{D}(0,r_2)$. We'll use the Abel criteria to establish the normal convergence. So, we have

\begin{align}
|a_nz^n| & =|a_n||z|^n \\
& \leq |\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r_2+\varepsilon}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}| r_2^n
\end{align}
Using the ML-inequality, we get that
\begin{align}
|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r_2+\varepsilon}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}| r_2^n & \leq \frac{r_2^n}{2\pi} \sup_{t\in[0,2\pi]}\left | \frac{f((r_2+\varepsilon)e^{it})(r_2+\varepsilon)e^{it}}{(r_2+\varepsilon)^{n+1}e^{i(n+1)t}} \right |2\pi(r_2+\varepsilon) \\
& \leq \frac{r_2^n}{2\pi} \sup_{t\in[0,2\pi]}\left | f((r_2+\varepsilon)e^{it})(r_2+\varepsilon) \right |\frac{2\pi(r_2+\varepsilon)}{(r_2+\varepsilon)^{n+1}} \\
& \leq \frac{r_2^n}{2\pi} \max_{|\zeta|=r_2+\varepsilon}|f(\zeta)| \frac{2\pi(r_2+\varepsilon)}{(r_2+\varepsilon)^{n+1}} \\
& = \max_{|\zeta|=r_2+\varepsilon}|f(\zeta)| \left (\frac{r_2}{(r_2+\varepsilon)}  \right )^n
\end{align}

And since $\frac{r_2}{(r_2+\varepsilon)}<1$, by the Abel criteria, the series is normally convergent.

My question is the follow, is my proof correct? I don't know if during the last steps involving the sup, I can really do what I did. Since $|e^{it}|=1$ for all $t\in[0,2\pi]$, we can simplify and so on.

Thanks for the reading, hope you can help me!